# magento 1.9 cash on delivery add Rs.50 fee without any extension

Tags: magento-1.9, cash-on-delivery

I want to add all **Cash On Delivery** fee `Rs.50` without use any extension.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For your question you don't want extension so try this code

https://github.com/yvoronoy/magento-extension-extra-fee

Comment: But that's an extension :/ Did you mean you didn't want to pay for a commercial extension?

Answer (score 0):

For those who are still searching for extra cod fee you can use this free module https://github.com/PHOENIX-MEDIA/Magento-CashOnDelivery. 
I'm using the same module also for extra fee on Card swipe on delivery.

I have implemented this in my website and it works perfect.

Answer (score -1):

You can use default **Flat Rate shipping Method** for Cash on Delivery.
[image]

Comment: I think this is not a correct way

Comment: If you are not using Table Rate or Flat Rate for your shipping method, you have to make an extension which you don't want.

Comment: wouldn't it anyway ask for payment on checkout from customer?